# Error creating an Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an issue with the Instagram API setup and am receiving the error "We don't approve multiple submissions for the same company. Please consolidate all your integrations under a single client_id." after submission.

This is a newly created Instagram user account dedicated for this new API so there aren't any other conflicting accounts.

Some helps would be appreciated!

Many thanks!

[image: Error image]

Comment: Did you create an API key before? You can better contact the customer service from Instagram/Facebook.

Comment: No it's the first time. Instagram has no customer support, I'd have to contact Facebook in that case.